# How to move selected cell data to an array in DataGrid programatically

Tags: c#, datagrid

Here is a code that moves all the data from datagrid to the array. But I want only selected data to be moved to this array. Selection may be done by mouse.

```
public List<double[]> ExtractGridData(DataGridView grid)
    {
        int numCols = grid.Columns.Count;
        List<double[]> list = new List<double[]>();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
        {
            if (row.IsNewRow) // skip the new row
                continue;
            double[] cellsData = new double[numCols];
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                if (cell.Value != null)
                    cellsData[cell.ColumnIndex] = Convert.ToDouble(cell.Value);
            list.Add(cellsData);
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`grid.SelectedRows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows.aspx) instead of `grid.Rows`.

You can also use [`grid.SelectedCell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedcells.aspx) if the [`SelectionMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionmode.aspx) is set to `CellSelect` and you need individual cell values:

```
List<double> cellsData = new List<double>();
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in grid.SelectedCells)
{
    if( cell.Value != null)
        cellsData.Add(Convert.ToDouble(cell.Value));
}
```

Comment: How do i set SelectionMode to CellSelect?

Comment: @user2049436 What do you mean "didn't work"? What happened exactly? In design mode, select your grid, bring the `Porperties` window (press `F4`), change `SelectionMode` to `CellSelect`. Or in code: `grid.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;`.

Comment: Am getting an exception even after selecting the rows.

Comment: In the code: "cellsData does not exist in current context" is the error.

Comment: @user2049436 Please look closely at the code in the answer. `cellsData` is defined by me, on the line before the `foreach` loop. What is the exception? Please read some books and learn how to really program in C# and Winforms.

Comment: The error was fixed. The program is now not taking multiple cells as input. Only one selected cell is working. Upon selecting multiple cells, am getting array out of bound exception.

Comment: @user2049436 No one can help you when you just say: "doesn't work", "I get exception", ... Please be specific. Learn the codes, instead of just copy-pasting them.

Comment: @user2049436 In what line? Where do you get the exception?